# Sci-fi short story about a scientist frustrated with the pace of life, who releases a virus that renders caffeine ineffective

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Last read this maybe 10 to 15 years ago.
Parts of the plot include civilisation slowly falling apart after caffeine stops working, the protagonist eventually figures out a counteragent that makes caffeine work again, but it needs to be consumed regularly. This counteragent is blue in color. Title of the short story might be a reference to morning or Monday blues.

Comment: It's not your story, but it does remind me of "The day coffee stopped working" by John Bailey Owen

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[Powered by Water](http://www.molvray.com/sf/pbw.htm)" by Mia Molvray

> The boss lifted a few forms from the top of a drift of papers covering his desk and much of his computer.
>
> "Caffeine," he said shortly, waving the sheets.
>
> Norman stiffened. Invisibly, he hoped, as the first fright receded. Had he been found out?
>
> "Caffeine's not working. Find out why." He shoved the sheets at Norman. "Could be a Nobel in it for this lab," he added, using an almost complete sentence in honor of the idea despite the effort it cost him.
>
> Gingerly, Norman took the papers. He pretended to study them to give himself time to frame a response. Fear flipped into hysterical humor as he almost chuckled at the irony of imagining Kriegel's lab covered in glory for finding the cure--until the media found out it had also created the original problem. In his mind's eye, Kriegel sputtered protestations about how he was shocked--shocked!--that anyone could think he would do such a thing for profit. But back to the problem at hand, and an appropriately tentative demeanor.

....

> He tried not to look at the three vials. He tried not to look at Rudi to see if she'd noticed them. She would probably make the connection in a heartbeat and then she had the know-how to track it down and prove it. After all, even Kriegel had noticed that caffeine in larger and larger doses was having less and less effect. But engineering an anti-caffeine gene was easy. Norman's genius lay in coming up with the perfect vector to carry the gene into everyone's cells: a modified cold virus that was entirely symptomless and perfectly catching. He had made himself immune, so everybody else slowed down while he did not. Now he usually headed home by six or seven instead of midnight, but he wanted to hold off on the antidote until he could go home at five. He wanted a life as well as a job.

....

> Norman frowned. He was trying to slow things down, damn it. Sometimes it seemed that no matter what you did, things just got worse. "You 'understand'? You haven't tried any of the--um-performance enhancers?" he asked with careful indifference.

....

> "Everybody just slows down and starts acting rational and having a life, instead of trying to find the cure for cancer while faxing letters to the President and talking to their divorce lawyer on their cell phone."
>
> Norman nodded numbly. That had been the idea.

....

> The pub was doing a roaring trade. Jovial workers lined up at the bar for more blue Bronco Brew. Orders for crates of it were coming in from as far away as Hong Kong. It was such wonderful beer they said. It had a marvelous effect on the whole system, it toned you up and made you feel on top of things. Why was it blue, asked reporters once the beer made the news. It was an old Romulan recipe, answered Norman with his best postdoctoral face. Vanessa arranged a contract with one of the largest names in brewing for facilities to make the stuff by the tanker ship. Money poured in. Rudi invested hers in the nicely recovering stock market.

Found with a search for `"science fiction" caffiene stops working`

Comment: Ohhhh, I was so close!